# Problem with mounting usb device FAT filesystem on Linux

Tags: usb, mount, filesystem, ext4, fat32

I copied an image on a usb stick with win32DiskManage. I want to copy this image on my beagleboneblack wich's system is `Linux`. The filesystem of the usb stick is `FAT`.

Now I want to mount a usb device on my Beaglebone. 
I do the following:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

I get:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

The command: `dmesg | tail` gives:

```
root@beaglebone:~#  dmesg | tail
[ 1170.155394] hub 1-0:1.0: port 1 enable change, status 00000503
[ 1171.483876] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 32GB   1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1171.497571] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 61702144 512-byte logical blocks: (31.5 GB/29.4 GiB)
[ 1171.498411] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1171.498458] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 1171.499253] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1171.507032]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1171.512322] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1189.507211] FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 1189.513288] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

I suppose the reason is that the file system is not FAT, when I copy the image on the usb device in windows I always formate it as FAT filesystem but when on the BB the command  `lsblk -f` gave :

```
root@beaglebone:~#  lsblk -f
NAME         FSTYPE LABEL      MOUNTPOINT
sdb
`-sdb1       ext4   BOOT
mmcblk0boot0
mmcblk0boot1
mmcblk0
|-mmcblk0p1  vfat   BEAGLEBONE
`-mmcblk0p2  ext4   rootfs     /
```

Why is it `ext4`?

When I mount the device as `ext4`, I can't find the image. And executing

```
dd if=/mnt/imagename.img of=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=4M
```

gives back :

```
dd: opening `/mnt/imagename.img': No such file or directory
```

I'll be thankfull for your help :D

Comment: This is very confusing for me. First you have command which says /dev/sda1, then you try to mount /dev/sde1, and in the end you show log saying about /dev/sdb1. Find out which is the right partition you want to mount. Then you can omit `-t vfat`, because mount will detect it by itself.

Comment: Looks like `sda1` is a partition on your HDD, not on your USB-device. The partition you want to mount is probably `sdb1`. Could you please add the complete output of `lsblk -f` to your question so we can see a bit more?

Comment: thx guys.. it's done

Comment: @mook765 I don't understand your point.. after I copied the image on the usb stick I want to mount it on the Beaglebone witch runs on linux.

Comment: I think copying a disk image to the partition `sdb1` changed the file-system too. But I wonder why the partitions then have different labels. There could also a problem with the UUID's of the filesystem, they should be unique. Copying a disk-image will create a file-system with the exact same UUID, you may check your UUID's with `lsblk -o NAME,UUID`, if necessary, change the UUID of `sdb1` to another value. You can also try to mount with out the `-t`-option with `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` so the used file-system will be detected automatically.

Comment: @mook765 The different labels were only because I copied codes from different tries.. Let's suppose the device is´sdb1´.  Now I could mountit as an ext4 filesystem. But when I do so I can't find the image that I copied on it with windows as FAT filesystem anymore.

Comment: You should explain exactly how you created the image and how you copied it to the USB-device. What does the successfully mounted partition `sdb1` contain? You say you don't find the image in it, but does contain it anything else?

Comment: @mook765 done .. I modified the question ..thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67643/discussion-between-mook765-and-ben-jo).